# What is the point of having asterisks before and after the search term while using the 'find' command?

Tags: command-line

What is the point of having asterisks before and after the search term here?

```
find ~ -name "*bash*"
```

I've learned so far that the asterisk means to find zero or more characters of the previous character so how does that apply in this command or is it altogether different here?

Comment: Without it, you are asking `find` to search in your $HOME directory (~) for files that have name "bash"; the \* characters allow for something|anything before and after the 'bash' which is a different meaning to 'bash' alone.

Comment: @guiverc [That](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1148962/2) was probably not the best way to escape asterisks for a terminal text. It lead to [this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1148962/3), distorted the original command.

Answer (score 2):

Without it, you are asking find to search in your $HOME directory (~) for files that have name "bash"; the * characters allow for something|anything before and after the 'bash' which is a different meaning to 'bash' alone.

`find ~ -name "bash"`

would find a file named "bash", not not `my_bash_script`.  The * before and after 'bash' change the meaning and allow it to find a file named `bash` and `my_bash_script`,

Answer (score 2):

What you refer to by zero or more characters is regex - that is advanced pattern matching used by tools like `grep` and `awk`.

In the command you have asterisk (`*`) means any character. The `-name` flag only looks at filenames when performing that match.

Tilde (`~`) signifies user's home directory, and note that find command is not aware of if. When the command is called the shell will perform  replacement and what the command will see when called is something like `/home/jdoe` instead.

Now, `find` (being a recursive command) will traverse `/home/jdoe` (signified by `~`) and every sub-directory of home directory matching any file that has the word `bash` in it so the matched files would be `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc-local` or even `~/Pictures/wabash_2019.png`

Now if you do want to use regex, that would be handled by `-regex` flag where this pattern would mean something else entirely and likely won't produce any output. I won't go into the details of regex because there are whole books on this subject. In this case regex is used for very basic pattern matching.

Comment: yes, I see I'm confusing it with the grep searches here..

Comment: does the find command list directories or just filenames?

Comment: It lists all types - directories, files, named pipes and named sockets, symlinks - unless you specify -type flag